# An error has occured with str on address book

Tags: python

Im making an address book and i got a problem. It's telling me that I have a problem with str and lists. I'm new to python so i dont really know what to do.
Here is the full program:

```
print("\n This is your address book.")

import os
import time

saveFile = open("ContactList.txt", "r")
ContactsString = saveFile.read()
saveFile.close()

Contacts = ContactsString.split('\n')

while '' in Contacts:
    Contacts.remove('')

def printContacts():
    index = 1
    for contact in Contacts:
        print("{}: {}".format(index, contact))
        index = index + 1

def addContact():
    print("You have chosen to add a new contact into your address book.")
    name = input("What's the contacts name? ")

    counter = Contacts.count(name)
    if counter == 0:
        address = input("Enter the address of " + name + ': ')
        email = input("Enter the email of " + name + ': ')
        Contacts.append([ name, address, email ])
    else:
        print("The contact already exists in the address book.")
        print("If you desire to change the contacts current information, enter nr 3 in the menu.")

def browseContacts():
    print("You have chosen to view all your contacts with their name, address and email." "\n")    
    for i in range(0, len(Contacts), 3):
        print(Contacts[i], Contacts[i + 1], Contacts[i + 2], '\n')

def searchContacts():
    print("\n You have chosen to search up a specific contact.")
    searchName = input("Enter the name of the contact that you want to search up: ")

    searchFound = False
    for i in range(0, len(Contacts), 3):
        if searchName == Contacts[i]:
            searchName = True
            break

    if searchFound == True:
        print(Contacts[i], Contacts[i + 1], Contacts[i + 2], "\n")
    else:
        print("We couldn't find " + searchName + " in the address book.")
        print("Check whether your spelling was correct or not.")
        time.sleep(4)

def deleteContact():
    print('\n You have chosen option 4, to delete a specific contact from your address book')
    printContacts()
    deletename = input(' Enter the name of the contact you wish to delete from your address book: ').title()

    deletefound = False
    for i in range(0, len(Contacts), 3): #finds the contact the user wants to delete. It only iterates through each third post so that it only goes through the names of the contact.
        if deletename == Contacts[i]:
            deletefound = True
            break

    if deletefound == True:
        Contacts.pop(i) # deletes the contact information from the list
        Contacts.pop(i)
        Contacts.pop(i)
        print('\n ' + deletename + 'has been removed from your address book')
    else:
        print('\n ' + deletename + "doesn't exist in the address book")

def modifyContacts():
    print("You have chosen option 5, to update a specific contact in your address book.")
    printContacts()
    newName = input("Enter the name of the contact you wish to update: ")

    modifyFound = False
    for i in range(0, len(Contacts), 3):
        if newName == Contacts[i]:
            modifyFound = True
            break

    if modifyFound == True:
        Contacts[i]       = input(' Enter the new name of '    + newName            + ': ')
        Contacts[i + 1]   = input(' Enter the new address of ' + Contacts[i] + ': ')
        Contacts[i + 2]   = input(' Enter the new e-mail of '  + Contacts[i] + ': ')
        print('\n The contact has now been updated')
    else:
        print("\n " + newName + " doesn't exist in the address book")
        print(" You can add " + newName + "to your address book by pressing 1 in the menu below")
        time.sleep(4)


running = True
while running == True:

    print('''
===================================================================
 Menu:

 1: Add new contact (press 1)
 2: Show all contacts (press 2)
 3: Show a specific contact (press 3)
 4: Delete contact (press 4)
 5: Update contact (press 5)
 6: Quit program (press 6)

===================================================================''')

    actionchoice = input('\n Please enter your choice of action: ')

    if actionchoice == '1':   
        addContact()

    elif actionchoice == '2':
        browseContacts()

    elif actionchoice == '3':
        searchContacts()

    elif actionchoice == '4':
        deleteContact()

    elif actionchoice == '5':
        modifyContacts()

    elif actionchoice == '6':
        print('\n Shutting down. Thank you for using the adressbook! \n')
        running = False

    else:
        print('\n The entered command does not exist within this program')
        print(' Please enter one of the actions shown in the menu: \n')
        time.sleep(4)


    saveFile = open("ContactList.txt", "w") 
    for x in range(0, len(Contacts), 3):
        saveFile.write("\n" + Contacts[x]     + "\n")
        saveFile.write(       Contacts[x + 1] + "\n")
        saveFile.write(       Contacts[x + 2] + "\n")
    saveFile.close()
```

The problem is in the end and the problem says:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
**can only concatenate str (not "list") to str**
  File "C:\Users\Anvandare\Documents\Programmering1\Arbetet\addressbook.py", line 162, in <module>
    saveFile.write("\n" + Contacts[x]     + "\n")
```

In other words, this is the problem:

```
saveFile.write("\n" + Contacts[x]     + "\n")
```

What am i supposed to do for it to work?

Comment: Don't put each field in a separate element of `Contacts`. Make it a list of dictionaries or tuples.

Comment: What does `print(Contacts[x])` show when that happens?

Comment: @Barmar , im sorry, im new and not really knowlegable to this, what exactly am i supposed to do?

Comment: Put that before the line that's getting the error. Then you'll see what the incorrect value of `Contacts[x]` is, which should help figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
Contacts.append([ name, address, email ])
```

This is not appending each variable as a separate element of the list, it's creating a nested list in `Contacts`. It should be:

```
Contacts.append(name)
Contacts.append(address)
Contacts.append(email)
```

or:

```
Concacts += [ name, address, email ]
```

You also need to fix `printContacts()` to process `Contacts` in groups of 3, like the rest of the code.

```
def printContacts():
    index = 1
    for i in range(0, len(Contacts), 3):
        print("{}: {} {} {}".format(index, *Contacts[i:i+3]))
        index = index + 1
```

IMHO it would be better for `Contacts` to be a list of dictionaries, but doing this would require a rewrite to 90% of your code and I'm not going to do that here.

Comment: Thank you so much Barmar! I'll fix it, but Contacts.appen(name) etc. will result in me getting a list with 1. name  2. address and 3. email, i would like them to be connected like this : name, address and email. How am i supposed to make them connected?

Comment: That's the way the rest of your code expects it. That's why you do `Contacts[x]`, `Contacts[x+1]`, and `Contacts[x+2]`.

Comment: yes but if you try to run the program , first add a contact and then choose to delete one, they will appear like this : 1: name , 2: address and 3: email , which is "wrong" and i would like to change it

Comment: `printContacts` needs to loop in increments of 3, just like `searchContacts` and `deleteContact` does.

Comment: Half your program tries to put a contact into a single list, the other half does them as separate elements. You need to pick one way and do it consistently.

Comment: thank you ill definitely look at it, but the problem is in adding contacts, because when i add contacts, they get seperated in different rows which i dont want

Comment: how should i code them differently to get it fixed?

Comment: I've added the fix to `printContacts`. I'm not going to do the full rewrite that's needed to make each contact a single element.

Comment: thank you so much god bless you! One more question, how do i add commas in between name, address and email?

Comment: Just put them in the format string. `"{}: {}, {}, {}"`. Why is that confusing?

Comment: thank you, im new so i dont really know how things work

Comment: i have another question , what does "can only concatenate str (not "bool") to str" mean? It appears in search contacts

Comment: It's because of `searchName = True`. That should have been `searchFound = True`. After that, you do `print("We couldn't find " + searchName + " in the address book.")`, and `searchName` is `True` rather than the name you were looking for.

Comment: but i have written searchFound = true and not searchName , or am i wrong?

Comment: Look at the line after `if searchName == Contacts[i]:`